# Is there any way to get FB # TAG post to webpage

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get only specific #TAG post on FB Page to php base website page.

How can I do this?

Is this possible to do in FB Apps?

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer possible with Graph API v2.0, because the search for public posts has been deprecated:

> Public Post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api